# converting file in order to print only the hostname and IP

Tags: linux, awk, sed, perl

I need to convert the following file example 1 to the file as appears on **example 2**

so it will print  machine name and IP but only in case "name" appears before host_name

- redhat03.rdns.com  10.10.29.66  not printed because "name" not appears before host_name

please advice what is the best way to do this convertion by awk or sed or perl one liners

example1

```
    "name" : "REDHAT",
    "host_name" : "linux01.rdns.com",
    "ip" : "10.10.29.61"
    "name" : "REDHAT",
    "host_name" : "linux02.rdns.com",
    "ip" : "10.10.29.62"
    "name" : "REDHAT",
    "host_name" : "linux03.rdns.com",
    "ip" : "10.10.29.63"
    "name" : "REDHAT",
    "host_name" : "redhat01.rdns.com",
    "ip" : "10.10.29.64"
    "name" : "REDHAT",
    "host_name" : "redhat02.rdns.com",
    "ip" : "10.10.29.65"
    "name" : "REDHAT",
    "host_name" : "redhat03.rdns.com",
    "ip" : "10.10.29.66"
    "host_name" : "redhat04.rdns.com",
    "ip" : "10.10.29.67"
    "name" : "REDHAT",
    "host_name" : "redhat05.rdns.com",
    "ip" : "10.10.29.68"
    "name" : "REDHAT",
    "host_name" : "redhat06.rdns.com",
    "ip" : "10.10.29.81"
    "name" : "REDHAT",
    "host_name" : "redhat07.rdns.com",
    "ip" : "10.10.29.82"
    "name" : "REDHAT",
    "host_name" : "redhat08.rdns.com",
    "ip" : "10.10.29.83"
    "name" : "REDHAT",
    "host_name" : "redhat09.rdns.com",
    "ip" : "10.10.29.84"
```

expected results

```
 linux01.rdns.com   10.10.29.61
 linux02.rdns.com   10.10.29.62
 linux03.rdns.com   10.10.29.63
 redhat01.rdns.com  10.10.29.64
 redhat02.rdns.com  10.10.29.65
 redhat03.rdns.com  10.10.29.66 
 redhat05.rdns.com  10.10.29.68
 redhat06.rdns.com  10.10.29.81
 redhat07.rdns.com  10.10.29.82
 redhat08.rdns.com  10.10.29.83
 redhat09.rdns.com  10.10.29.84
```

Comment: you meant `redhat04.rdns.com` is not printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`awk`** solution:

```
awk '/ip/ && NR-1==h_num && NR-2==n{ 
         r=h" "$3; gsub(/[,"]+/, "", r); print r 
     }
     /"host_name"/{ h_num=NR; h=$3 }
     /"name"/{ n=NR }' file
```

The output:

```
linux01.rdns.com 10.10.29.61
linux02.rdns.com 10.10.29.62
linux03.rdns.com 10.10.29.63
redhat01.rdns.com 10.10.29.64
redhat02.rdns.com 10.10.29.65
redhat03.rdns.com 10.10.29.66
redhat05.rdns.com 10.10.29.68
redhat06.rdns.com 10.10.29.81
redhat07.rdns.com 10.10.29.82
redhat08.rdns.com 10.10.29.83
redhat09.rdns.com 10.10.29.84
```

Comment: output should not inc;ude the  " or ,  ( only hostnames and IP's

Comment: question why if I redirect the output to file - the I get shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory

Comment: example cat file | awk '/ip/ && NR-1==h_num && NR-2==n{ 
         r=h" "$3; gsub(/[,"]+/, "", r); print r 
     }
     /"host_name"/{ h_num=NR; h=$3 }
     /"name"/{ n=NR }' > new_file

Comment: @jango, this `example cat file | awk ...` is bad practice. Don't take that habit. Use `awk '/ip/ && NR-1==h_num && NR-2==n{ r=h" "$3; gsub(/[,"]+/, "", r); print r } /"host_name"/{ h_num=NR; h=$3 } /"name"/{ n=NR }' yourfile > new_file`. Besides, `file` is abstracted, you should specify your own actual file name

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk -F' +|:|,|"' '/"name"/{flag=1;next} flag && /"host_name"/{val1=$(NF-2);next} flag && /"ip"/{print val1,$(NF-1);flag=""}'   Input_file
```

Comment: work partial because its print the redhat04.rdns.com  10.10.29.67 line , its not should to print it because "name" not exists before host_name

Comment: @jango, name should be `REDHAT`? or it should simply exist?

Comment: just need to check the word "name" if exist then need to print if name not exists then no need to print the next line hostname & ip

Comment: @jango, please check my edited code now and let me know if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below sed oneliner to get the result. As checked its works fine

```
sed -n '/host_name/,+1p' filename  | awk -F ":" '{print $2}'  | sed 's/"//g' |sed "s/,//g" | sed "N;s/\n/ /g"
```

output

```
linux01.rdns.com  10.10.29.61
 linux02.rdns.com  10.10.29.62
 linux03.rdns.com  10.10.29.63
 redhat01.rdns.com  10.10.29.64
 redhat02.rdns.com  10.10.29.65
 redhat03.rdns.com  10.10.29.66
 redhat04.rdns.com  10.10.29.67
 redhat05.rdns.com  10.10.29.68
 redhat06.rdns.com  10.10.29.81
 redhat07.rdns.com  10.10.29.82
 redhat08.rdns.com  10.10.29.83
 redhat09.rdns.com  10.10.29.84
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another awk solution

```
awk -F'|:|,|"' '/"name"/{getline; printf $5; getline; print "  "$5}' file1
```

Comment: this does not provide any check if `name` line is followed by `host_name` and `ip` lines

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest you are correct. I took the liberty of providing the most simple command I could identify and still meet the constraints of the stated problem. I understood that the case would be that the "name line" would be the missing parameter and not any of the other lines based on jango's reply to RavinderSingh13 "just need to check the word "name" if exist then..."